# Xcode GM: no swift language for OS X command line tool project?

Tags: swift, xcode6, command-line-tool

I had a command line tool project in swift. after upgraded to Xcode GM. It doesn't work anymore. Furthermore, It seems the Swift language choice is removed from the create project wizard?

Is this temporarily in GM, or I missed some news that Apple decide to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode 6 GM is for iOS Swift development. Xcode 6.1 Beta is for OS X / iOS Swift development.

[Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Any references to prove that? And it's Xcode not XCode.

Comment: The developer documentation. And fine, whatever. Xcode. Edit: [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html) link added to post.

Comment: When claiming that the documentation says something, it's traditional to provide a link or at least a specific reference. There's an awful lot of documentation to sort through otherwise.

Comment: When wondering that an IDE might have removed a feature, it's traditional to read the release notes before asking for help. Sorry I took the time to clarify things.

Comment: Stay cool. We just wanted to help you improving your answer. And now your answer is perfect. +1

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry, hadn't had my coffee yet. *sips*